# How to remove the first character of every string in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

for a coding assignment we need to create a card game. For the coding part of the game we decided to make one string array that has all the cards in it. In this array it tells you the suit and value of the card. What we also want to do is to be able to remove the characters that identify the suit so that we can convert it from a string to an int to add up points at the end. I've tried numerous methods to get what I want in having an array of cards that can be converted later into an int from using an intrstream to fill 1-52 and then assigning values based on ranges n-n =spades etc., to trying to learn how to use enums since we haven't learned about those yet, and from looking at other peoples code who are doing a similar thing.

TLDR: I'm trying to just have this for each loop go through each string and remove the first character. Doesn't work.

```
String[] deck =
  {"DA, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, DJ, DQ, DK, SA, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10, SJ, SQ, SK, HA, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, H7, H8, H9, H10, HJ, HQ, HK, CA, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, CJ, CQ, CK"};
String[] points = new String[deck.length];
for (int i = 0;i<deck.length;i++ ) {
    points[i] = deck[i].substring(0);
  }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
```

Comment: How specifically does it not work. What are you seeing and what is expected?

Comment: when I was typing out my response of what its doing as opposed to what is intended I realized my mistake. Every element in this array in one string, instead of a list of strings. If you change it to an actual array of strings it works. Your comment helped me figure it out lol thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be full answer but first of all you are defining one element array. I would recommend [`jshell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8) (with jdk9+) which is java REPL to play with java code and see how it reacts.

```
jshell> String[] deck = {"apple, banana, cat"}
deck ==> String[1] { "apple, banana, cat" }
```

You instead want to separate elements, and see the size is 3.

```
jshell> String[] deck = {"apple", "banana", "cat"}
deck ==> String[3] {"apple", "banana", "cat"}
```

Then you should be able to `.substring(1)` to get the card point ignoring the first char and convert it to integer later.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] deck = {
            "DA",
            "D2",
            "D3",
            "D4",
            "D5",
            "D6",
            "D7",
            "D8",
            "D9",
            "D10",
            "DJ",
            "DQ",
            "DK",
            "SA",
            "S2",
            "S3",
            "S4",
            "S5",
            "S6",
            "S7",
            "S8",
            "S9",
            "S10",
            "SJ",
            "SQ",
            "SK",
            "HA",
            "H2",
            "H3",
            "H4",
            "H5",
            "H6",
            "H7",
            "H8",
            "H9",
            "H10",
            "HJ",
            "HQ",
            "HK",
            "CA",
            "C2",
            "C3",
            "C4",
            "C5",
            "C6",
            "C7",
            "C8",
            "C9",
            "C10",
            "CJ",
            "CQ",
            "CK"
    };

    String[] points = new String[deck.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        points[i] = deck[i].substring(1);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
}
```

output:

```
[A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K]
```

Comment: Yeah after thinking about what was going wrong I realized my error of having everything as one element. Thank you for your reply.